# glUniform1i(int, Bool) vs. glUniform1i(int, int)

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, gpuimage, android-gpuimageview

I'm trying to port some OpenGLES code from iOS to Android.

In iOS I have this code:

```
- (void)setColorOn:(BOOL)yes
{
    glUniform1i(colorOnUniform, yes);
}
```

where the glUniform1i() method takes an Integer as a Uniform location and a Boolean.

In Android, the closest I can get is this:

```
public void setColorOn() {
        GLES20.glUniform1i(colorOnUniform, 0);
}
```

where the glUniform1i() method takes an Integer as a Uniform location and another Integer, I think as a texture id...

I've dug around the Kronos documentation, but can't seem to find a proper translation ...

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait what? The `glUniform1i` takes 2 integers in both cases. Why the developer inserted a boolean value I have no idea. Anyway the iOS boolean value translates as `YES`(true) = 1 and `NO`(false) = 0. This value is probably used in shader as `if(colorOnUniform == 0)...; else...;`

This method should probably be like:

```
- (void)setColorOn:(BOOL)yes
{
    glUniform1i(colorOnUniform, yes?1:0);
}
```

Issue resolved...

Comment: haha.. totally... never thought about the BOOL being used as an Int for each case... thanks for the catch !

Comment: would explain why I was unable to find the method definition !